# Twilio MMS Request Timeout error when using S3 for image storage

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js, twilio, connection-timeout

I'm storing images on Amazon S3 and my Twilio MMS request keeps getting a "Request Timeout" error (I'm assuming because the function has to find & download the image from S3).

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: How large is your image?

Comment: The largest image is 53KB. The average image is about 20KB. I know its the images, because when I comment out the 'mediaUrl' data from the message being sent, it sends it without any errors. If I just console.log the mediaUrl, it pics up the S3 link without hesitation. When I try to send the mediaUrl through the message (using Heroku), thats when it receives the Request Timeout error.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout parameters? Also, test if the permissions on the S3 objects are right.

Comment: @parkeragee, Did you ever figure this out? I am having trouble using the mediaUrl parameter with an s3 image as well. I don't get any error, the message just fails to send.